# What's the difference between view bounds and type bounds implementing evidence keyword?

Tags: scala

I'm not sure if I've got the terminology down right in the title, but what's the difference between this:

```
class Container[A <% Int] { def addIt(x: A) = 123 + x }
```

and this:

```
class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt(implicit evidence: A =:= Int) = 123 + value }
```

I suppose the question is why would I use one form of type bound over another?  Is it simply a matter of being able to apply a type bound at different parts of the code (eg in the parameter list vs the body)?

Also, the documents say that methods may ask for "evidence" for a type rather then using other objects for type checking then provide the second code snippet.  What kind of evidence are they referring to?

Note: this is regarding [this](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html) article on advanced types.

Comment: View bounds are deprecated, aren't they?

Comment: Change `evidence` to `A => Int` and these are equivalent.

Comment: @TravisBrown Only kind of though? Since one is implemented at the class level, and the other on the method.

Comment: @m-z Yeah, sorry—wasn't paying close enough attention. Put them at the same level and one would be syntactic sugar for the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*View bounds* are for when you want use a type that is *viewable* as another type. In your example, you want `A` to be *viewable* as `Int`. And what that means is we want *any* implicit conversion in scope from `A => Int`.

ie. it is the same as:

```
class Container(implicit evidence: A => Int) { def addIt(x: A) = 123 + x }
```

They are also [deprecated](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2909). That should be reason enough to avoid them.

---

*Type bounds* is not the correct term for your second example. They are for strictly bounding the types of a parameter from above or below. A *type bound* would look like this:

```
class Container[A <: Int] { def addIt(x: A) = 123 + x }
```

In this example `A` must be strictly bounded above by `Int`. Implicit conversions cannot apply.

---

I'm not sure if there's really a name for your second example, but it differs from *view bounds* in that it requires an instance of the type class `=:=` seen [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L393-402). It is similar to view bounds in that `=:=` witnesses that `A` is the same as `Int`, and therefore allows `A` to be converted explicitly to `Int`. However, it requires an instance of the type class `=:=[A, Int]` to exist, and not just *any* implicit conversion from `A => Int`.

---

Your two examples are kind of fundamentally different though. The first requires the *view bound* on the class itself, where the second requires the type evidence on the method. That is, the first example does not allow instances of `Container[String]` to exist at all (without an implicit conversion available), but the second one does. The second example happily allows you to construct a `Container[String]`, but will not let you use the `addIt` method, unless you have evidence that `String =:= Int`.

By *evidence* we mean either an implicit conversion to the type we're interested in (`A => Int`), or an instance of the type class `=:=` that witnesses the equality. For types that are actually the same, we have those automatically generated in [Predef (earlier link)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L393-402).

Comment: `=:=` is a type constraint. It's not part of the language, just something in the standard library — a type with a funny name.